# Importing images to my CSS(SASS) file in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm very new at javascript frameworks and webpack and I'm just trying to import an image in my css file.

Thats my project structure;

[image: My Project Structure]

Thats my next.config.js;

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS( withSass( withImages({
    webpack (config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        });
        return config
    }
})));
```

Main.scss File;

```
$font-type: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$primary-color: #ff5e1f;

body {
    font-family: $font-type;

    header {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100px;

        a.logo {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background: url('../images/logo.png');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just trying use my logo and there is nothing wrong in the terminal;

[image: MyTerminalImage]

But when I go to my website and developer tools, the url look like this;

```
background: url(/_next/static/images/logo-ea62a25….png);
```

And when I open the URL nothing shows(img not loaded) in Google Chrome and also in Firefox gives an error;

```
The image "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/images/logo-ea62a2595859a68f77a6cc473535b8f5.png" canot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

Maybe it's a dumb problem, sorry for that but I couldn't handle it :/
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found solution, I used file-loader instead of url-loader.

I changed my next.config.js file like this;

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS( withSass( withImages({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
})));
```

And it works :)
(Also don't forget to install file-loader with npm)

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```